# The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml

I have been using an external API (SFML) with C++, which required that I added some dll files to my install of MinGW. While the program compiles and runs fine for me, it will not run on any other computers. When attempting to run on other computers this error pops up:

`The proecdure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library`, followed by the *.exe location.

My friend mentioned that I could bundle MinGW in with my program and edit the users PATH, but I have not found any documentation online about how to do this. I would be much obliged if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either ship the compiler´s runtime library with your executable, or else link it statically into your program.

Comment: How would I link MinGW statically into the program? I'm using Code::Blocks on Windows.

Comment: Look into the compiler manual (gcc/g++) I believe that `-static-libgcc` might suffice, you might need to do something else.